# Bluetooth doesn't work

Tags: windows-8, bluetooth

After Windows 8 installation, bluetooth didn't work. When I tried to receive a file it threw me the following error:

> Bluetooth file transfer not completed
>    Windows was unable to transfer
>   some files
>    And invalid argument was supplied

[image: Bluetooth error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason bluetooth might not work is because it might be disabled by default. To enable it open Computer Management. *How to open Computer management is at the bottom*

Then click on **Services and Applications** and then on **Services**. Find **Bluetooth Support Device**, then *right click* on it and choose **Properties**.

[image: open bluetooth properties]

Then press **start** and, if you don't want to turn it on manually set your *prefered startup type*

[image: start bluetoth]

### How to open Computer Management:

- **Right click on computer in Explorer**

  [image: computer manage]
- **type 'compmgmt.msc' in Search** (just press Win logo and type it in)

[image: search]

- **Open run (using <kbd>Win logo</kbd> +  <kbd>r</kbd> ) and type 'compmgmt.msc' in and press enter**

[image: run]